# Cant retrieve a value from Sass map

Tags: css, sass

I have a map of colors in my variable.scss

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: $primary,
  secondary: $secondary,
  gray-medium-emphasis: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
  gray-border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
  gray-low-emphasis: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)
);
```

In other file I want to reach this gray-medium-emphasis . I'm trying with this code

```
.calendar-outline-btn {
  outline: 1px solid get($theme-colors, gray-border);
  padding-top: 0.3125em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125em;
  color: get($theme-colors, gray-medium-emphasis);
}
```

When I run build on this, I've got this error:

```
SassError: (primary: #29245c, secondary: #297d94, gray-medium-emphasis: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), gray-border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), gray-low-emphasis: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)) isn't a valid CSS value.
  ╷
4 │   outline: 1px solid get($theme-colors, gray-border);
  │                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\arrangements\calendar\calendar.component.scss 4:26  root stylesheet
```

Before that, I tried `map-get`, but then I've got an error from lint. I also tried map.get but then it was also throwing error like

```
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "map".
  ╷
4 │   outline: 1px solid map.get($theme-colors, gray-border);
  │                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\arrangements\calendar\calendar.component.scss 4:22  root stylesheet
```

Comment: Try adding `@use 'sass:map';` to the top of the file before using `map.get`.

Comment: Yeap. This worked.